# How to fix "lint-staged failed due to a git error"

Tags: javascript, git, lint-staged

For some reason, lint-staged keeps failing, showing the `lint-staged due to a git error`.

Using version v13.0.3.

```
  ✖ lint-staged failed due to a git error.
 Cleaning up temporary files...
  Any lost modifications can be restored from a git stash:

    > git stash list
    stash@{0}: automatic lint-staged backup
    > git stash apply --index stash@{0}
```

Comment: see related issue on github https://github.com/okonet/lint-staged/issues/929

Answer (score 1):

Solved this issue. I checked my `.git` folder and found a `lint-staged_unstaged.patch` file. I deleted that and resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a similar problem, which turned out to be caused by file permissions. I was able to resolve the issue by by fixing the permissions.

I used the below script to change it for all files.

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) <path_to_repo>
```

After executing this command, the issue was resolved.

Answer (score 1):

first you need to check the git log file, and see the message it gaves you, for example, this was my git logs :

> ⧗   input: feat: :sparkles: (**here, is my commit message**)
>
> (**here, is the longer description of my commit message**) ✖   header
> must not be longer than 100 characters, current length is 102
> [header-max-length]
>
> ✖   found 1 problems, 0 warnings ⓘ   Get help:
> https://github.com/conventional-changelog/commitlint/#what-is-commitlint
>
> husky - commit-msg hook exited with code 1 (error)

as you can see the problem is about the header (commit message) exceeding the header-max-length of 100 characters, so you should make it shorter.

Answer (score -1):

my problem fixed by run the following command:

```
yarn lint (eslint --fix "src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}" & yarn format)
```